# Browser PointerEvent interface support

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

How can I determine if the browser that is executing my javascript code will support the PointerEvent interface? I would like to use it if it is available and revert to my existing code if it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.PointerEvent) {
    // do PointerEvent stuff here
} else {
    // your existing code here
}
```

`PointerEvent` is a constructor, so if the interface is supported it will return this constructor, which is truthy (equivalent to `true`). If it is not supported (such as in Firefox), it will return `undefined`, which is falsey (equivalent to `false`) and the if condition will fail, reverting to your existing code.

See the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) for more information